# create and initialize dictionary in typescript in same line

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary using `TypeScript` and initialize it in same line instead of first creating and then populating the value like below

```
var persons: { [id: string] : IPerson; } = {};
persons["p1"] = { firstName: "F1", lastname: "L1" };
```

How do I combine the above into one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create an object. Objects in ECMAScripts are associative arrays.

Here is your example as object:

```
const persons: { [id: string] : IPerson; } = {
  p1: { firstName: "F1", lastname: "L1" }
};
```

It's also better to use `const` or `let` instead of `var`.